# Express with ReactJS not updating get function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have an express/react app which runs just fine, it is a single-page app. I needed to make some changes on the server side regarding authentication, but I noticed that running the express server my app was not serving the updated .get function. Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Old function

```
app.get('/app/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})
```

New function:

```
app.get('/app/', async (req, res) => {
    const authorized = await checkSession(req)
    if (!authorized) {  res.redirect('/login'); return}
    res.send("OK")
})
```

I suppose I should get a plain `OK` as a response in the browser, but even changing the server port, browser or anything I can think of I get the old page. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash on the first parameter of `app.get()`:

```
app.get('/app', async (req, res) => {
    const authorized = await checkSession(req)
    if (!authorized) {  res.redirect('/login'); return}
    res.send("OK")
})
```

Answer (score -1):

try to remove async/await because when you use this checkSession return one promise and continue to execute the rest os the code in this case you have to wait the return of checkSession before verify if is authorized.

Comment: `checkSession` is being `await`-ed. therefore it's not a `Promise` being returned.